# UIAlertView not popping every time

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a table view, and I have a method that gets called every time you click on a row. But the problem is, the first few times I click on those rows nothing happens, and after like 3 times it works as intended. What can cause this? Here is the code:

```
    - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hey, do you see the disclosure button?"
                                                    message:@"Touch that to drill down instead"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Won't happen again"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you implemented `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`

which should be

`- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 2):

Replace `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`  to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace "didDeselectRowAtIndexPath" to "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".
Because it should work while selecting the row not while deselecting the row.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hey, do you see the disclosure button?"
                                                    message:@"Touch that to drill down instead"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Won't happen again"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

This should be resolve your problem